# XMPP bot status message on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp, bots

GAE XMPP documentation states that is not possible to set status message for an app ( https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#Google_Talk_User_Status ).

On other hand, I've vark IM client has status message set. Obviously it is not hosted on GAE, 
but it is possible to set status message for app.

I have to dig under the hood, but wonder it there are any python references regarding this topic ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you have an example of an App Engine XMPP bot with its status message set, or some other reason you think this may be possible? The docs are pretty clear about it not being possible...

Comment: sorry for late reply. I've set bot on appengine and it is working like charm. But, I've been using advaark for a while and it has status message set and changed over time. Just wondering if someone talked this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html#Sending_Application_Status

You can set the status message through the send_presence method:

```
xmpp.send_presence(to_jid, status="My app's status")
```